# SUM previous value in php

Tags: php, mysql, sum

How can I create a function which can `SUM` the previous row with the new row and show me the result per each row?.

Like this in the column"SALDO":

```
| Cantidad           | nombre del producto | Precio compra | Precio DNM | Precio venta | Total compra | Saldo   | 
+--------------------+---------------------+---------------+------------+--------------+--------------+---------+
|                 14 | Sargenorig          |          6.00 |       9.00 |        10.00 |           84 |      84 | 
|                  9 | nombre producto     |        100.00 |     100.00 |       120.00 |          900 |     984 | 
| Total de productos |                     |               |            |              | Total        | Reporte | 
| 23                 |                     |               |            |              |              |     984 |
```

***tExiste*** is the total of product quantity this is the sum of all existence minus the sum of all the sales of each product

***Tott*** is the total of total purchases this is the sum of all existence minus the sum of all the sales of each product, the result is multiplied by the purchase price of each product

```
$sql = "SELECT nombreProd, compra, venta, dnm, 
SUM(existencia - vendido) AS tExiste, 
 (SUM(existencia - vendido) * compra) AS Tott
FROM PRODUCTOS WHERE f_producto BETWEEN 
'".$fromdate."' AND '".$todate."' GROUP BY code 
ORDER BY id DESC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo '
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>'.$row["tExiste"].'</td>
                <td class="center">'.$row["nombreProd"].'</td>
                <td class="center">
                <span class="add-on">'.$moneda.' </span>'.$row["compra"].'
                </td>
                <td class="center">
                <span class="add-on">'.$moneda.' </span>'.$row["dnm"].'
                </td>
                <td class="center">
                <span class="add-on">'.$moneda.' </span>'.$row["venta"].'
                </td>
                <td>
                <span class="add-on">'.$moneda.' </span>'.$row["Tott"].'
                </td>    
                <td>
                <span class="add-on">'.$moneda.' </span>
                </td>  // Here is where I need show the sum of each previous row with the new one              
            </tr>                         
        </tbody>
    '; }
```

and for last I need to show the total amount of those `SUM`

---

EDIT

I need to sum the previous Tott to the next Tott (Tott + Tott), not the sum of existence with the total (tExiste + Tott)...

e.g.: R1 : 84 + R2 : 900 = 984 + R3 : 150 = 1134...etc

Thank you

Comment: inside the while store the current "total" value and parse it at the end of the row. Before the end of the while, increase that value by the last amount you have added. is $row["Tott"] the "Total Compra" coloumn of your html table?

Comment: @briosheje yes it is

Comment: You can do it in mysql with user variables,it is ugly but possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were you, I'd just do a simple sum in PHP of all the values you need summed and `echo` that out (I didn't follow which you needed summed so I gave you an example). I always recommend that, if possible, you should have PHP do the work and not your database.

```
$prev = 0;
while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
echo '
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>'.$row["tExiste"].'</td>
            <td class="center">'.$row["nombreProd"].'</td>
            <td class="center">
            <span class="add-on">'.$moneda.' </span>'.$row["compra"].'
            </td>
            <td class="center">
            <span class="add-on">'.$moneda.' </span>'.$row["dnm"].'
            </td>
            <td class="center">
            <span class="add-on">'.$moneda.' </span>'.$row["venta"].'
            </td>
            <td>
            <span class="add-on">'.$moneda.' </span>'.$row["Tott"].'
            </td>    
            <td>
            <span class="add-on">'.$moneda.' </span>
            </td>
            <td>' . ($row["Tott"] + $prev) . '</td>   
        </tr>                         
    </tbody>
';
$prev = $row["Tott"];
}
```

Comment: Yes pretty easy way to do that +1

Comment: @machavity, I need to sum the previous Tott to the next Tott (Tott + Tott), not the sum of existence with the total (tExiste + Tott)... e.g.: 84+900=984

Comment: @user3236149 I've adjusted my answer to do that

Comment: @Machavity thank you that is!! But is really rare because when I put `$prev = 0;` show me 0 in second line (900+0=900), but when I change to `$prev = $prev;` works..  (900+84=984) ...

Answer (score 0):

You can get the total through SQL with [WITH ROLLUP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html).

From documentation

```
SELECT IFNULL(year,"Total") as year, SUM(profit) FROM sales GROUP BY year WITH ROLLUP;


+-------+-------------+
| year  | SUM(profit) |
+-------+-------------+
|  2000 |        4525 |
|  2001 |        3010 |
| Total |        7535 |
+-------+-------------+
```

Comment: thank you but I need to sum the previous Tott to the next Tott (Tott + Tott), not the sum of existence with the total (tExiste + Tott)... e.g.: 84+900+150=1134 ... etc